# Initialize autocomplete when cloning row in table

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

i need to initialize my autocomplete fields every time a clone a row in my table. Up to now is only initializing my first row when the page loads.  Here is my code http://jsfiddle.net/4XZMb/951/

```
function addRow(){

    var numberExistingRows = 1;
    //  use "ADD" button to add new row

    $('#add_row').click(function() {
        // keep track of number of rows for input names
        numberExistingRows++;

        // clone a row
        var $row = $('.dataRow:last').clone();

        $row.find('.deleteRow').click(deleteRow);

        // strip previous values and fix names of inputs
        $row.find('input').each(function() {
            var $input = $(this); // cache this input into jQuery object in lieu of using $(this) in below functions for clarity and performance

            $input.val(""); // reset value to none

            // fix names
            var thisInputName = $input.attr('id');
            $input.attr('id', thisInputName);
        });

        $('#tableSo').append($row);

        return false;

    });   

}
```

Comment: You are cloning rows with `id`'s. This is going to cause some problems. I suggest changing them to classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated your [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4XZMb/952/).

I changed the `id`'s to classes so that there is no conflict with duplicate `id`'s.

```
var autocompleteSo = function(row){
    var $row = $(row)
    $row.find( ".tableService" ).autocomplete({
            source: 'services/add_services.php?servtype=1',
            select: function(event, ui) {
            $('.id_servtype').val(ui.item.id);

        }
     });

     $row.find( ".soClient" ).autocomplete({
            source: 'salesorders/add_sales_order.php?client=1',
            select: function(event, ui) {
            $('.id_client').val(ui.item.id);

        }
     });

     $row.find( ".tableProject" ).autocomplete({
            source: 'salesorders/add_sales_order.php?project=1',
            select: function(event, ui) {
            $('.id_project').val(ui.item.id);

        }
     });
}
```

And then just after the append of the row, I would run this code.

```
$('#tableSo').append($row);
autocompleteSo($('#tableSo tr').eq(numberExistingRows - 1));
```

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple elements with the same ID. This is not valid HTML. Instead use a class that specifies that it is an a specific type of auto-complete and then select within your new row for that class to initialize.

```
function autocompleteSo(row){

    row.find( ".tableService" ).autocomplete({
            source: 'services/add_services.php?servtype=1',
            select: function(event, ui) {
            row.find('.id_servtype').val(ui.item.id);

        }
     });

     row.find( "soClient" ).autocomplete({
            source: 'salesorders/add_sales_order.php?client=1',
            select: function(event, ui) {
            row.find('id_client').val(ui.item.id);

        }
     });

     row.find( "tableProject" ).autocomplete({
            source: 'salesorders/add_sales_order.php?project=1',
            select: function(event, ui) {
            row.find('id_project').val(ui.item.id);

        }
     });
}
```

Something like this, and then you call autocompleteSo when a row is created.

```
 <tr class="dataRow soRows">
     <td>
         <input type="text" class="input-medium tableService" name="tableService" />
         <input type="hidden" class="id_servtype" name="id_servtype[]" />
     </td>
     ...
```